# Twig: Convert time format

Tags: templating, datetime, format, conversion

I have a video Object with a duration property formatted in [SCORM 2004 time format](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/ISOTimeForSCORM.htm). Like so: **PT51M55S**. How do i convert this into a human readable time format like: **51:55**? `date()` does not seem to work obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is possible in Twig alone, but it should be easy enough in PHP.

To do that, you could write a Craft [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that adds a custom Twig extension that has a ScormIt filter that uses PHP's [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) class to output it in the format that you're looking for.

That way, you could do something like:

```
{{ videoObject.duration|ScormIt }}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad. Might be a good reason to get into writing a plugin. Seems feasible, even for me. :)

Comment: If @low can do it, anyone can. You can use his RegEx twig filter as a starting point: https://github.com/low/low_regex